# Planning with OMPL using a subset of joints

Tags: ros, motion-planners

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to be able to treat the PR2 as a planar three link manipulator and test out some built in planners (openrave or OMPL).

Is there a way to restrict openrave and/or OMPL to use only the shoulder pan, elbow flex, and wrist flex joint of the PR2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9300/planning-with-ompl-using-a-subset-of-joints/) by [Advait Jain](https://answers.ros.org/users/219/advait-jain/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2011-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes,

ompl_ros_interface is setup to plan for a group of joints - you can setup a group to consist of just those three joints. When you make a planning request, you do have to make sure you specify where the other joints of the robot should be - they will stay fixed at those positions for planning.

Let me know if you run into problems.

---

Originally posted by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) with karma: 1304 on 2011-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0